# Does integral closure commute with pushforward

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, blow-ups

Suppose that $\pi : Y \to X$ is a proper birational morphism between normal varieties (schemes, whatever).  Suppose that $I$ is an ideal sheaf on $Y$.

One can form $\pi_* I$ and construct an ideal sheaf on $X$.  If $\overline{\bullet}$ denotes integral closure of ideals, then my question is compactly stated as:

**Question:** Is $\pi_* \overline{I} = \overline{\pi_* I}$?

Let me mention that one containment is obvious, indeed $\pi_* \overline{I}$ is integrally closed and contains $\pi_* I$, so certainly $\pi_* \overline{I} \supseteq \overline{\pi_* I}$.

However, I don't quite see how to get the other containment.  Let me run through the obvious attempt (which also gives the containment above) just for the record.

Let $f : Y' \to Y$ be the normalized blowup of both $I$ and $\pi_* I \cdot \mathcal{O}_Y$ and let $h : Y' \to X$ be the composition.  Write $I \cdot \mathcal{O}_{Y'} = \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-E)$ and $\pi_* I \cdot \mathcal{O}_{Y'} = \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-D)$.  Since certainly $\pi_* I \cdot \mathcal{O}_Y \subseteq I$, we have that $ \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-D) \subseteq  \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-E)$.  Now observe that

$$
\overline{\pi_* I} = h_* \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-D) \subseteq h_* \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-E) = \pi_* f_* \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-E) = \pi_* \overline{I}.
$$

So to get equality we need $h_* \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-D) \subseteq h_* \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-E)$ to be equality.  This looks like some assertion about $$h_* \mathcal{O}_{D-E}(-E)$$ being zero (modulo some conditions about singularities of $X$, assume they are mild and in characteristic zero to start if you want).  I don't see any good reason to assume this is zero.   Assume resolution of singularities in characteristic zero if it helps to assume that $Y'$ is smooth and $D, E$ are SNC.

Anyway, after all that my guess is that my question has a negative answer.

**Question:** Does anyone know a counter example off the top of their head?

Comment: What if we take $Y$ to be the normalization of $X$ and $X$ not normal with $I=\mathcal{O}_Y$? Then $\pi_*I$ is not an ideal sheaf on $X$.

Comment: Sure, that's true.  But let's assume $X$ is normal.  Indeed, if not we have to be a little more careful about how I define integral closure...

Comment: One could imagine finding many ideals $I_t$ on a variety $S$ such that $\overline{I}_t =I_0$ for some fixed ideal $I_0$. These ideals could be parameterized by a variety $T$, giving an ideal in $S \times T$. If $T$ is not affine, it seems quite likely that the pushforward of $I$ along the projection $S \times T \to S$ would be smaller than any $I_t$ and have a smaller integral closure, producing a counterexample. Is $T$ always affine?